# Keyboard automatic resign first responder

Tags: ios

I am using a `UIPageController` which is contain multiple view controller.

I switch From ViewController "A" to ViewController "B" or "B" to "C". "C" view controller has a `UITextField`. When i switch "B" to "C", the key board will appear for small time and automatically disappear. i am not calling the resign first responder but it automatically resign first responder.

what is the actual problem? could anyone tell me ? it will be great help for me.

Comment: can you check your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods to see if you have some call to you UITextField?

Comment: no i am calling anything in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. this two method just empty.

Comment: @Asaduzzaman Shuvro, Is tableview.reloadData() you are calling in any of the controller?

Comment: no i am not using any tableview. @Rohi

Answer (score 0):

First you will forcefully resign the keyboard of your textfield in viewWillAppear method. I faced the same issue in my project, and i solve that by the following code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [yourTextfield resignFirstResponder];

    // if you want the keyboard to show apply the following code

    [yourTextfield becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanations